# Why doesn't the sequel object have a setOwner method in this case?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm new to sequelizer, can't figure out why this is causing the error of setOwner not being a function. I thought maybe it was getting executed in the wrong context, but I'm logging out the object it is called on and it looks like the large sequelize object... here is my code and errors if anyone can point me in the right direction.

SEED FILE:

```
const { Vegetable, Gardener, Plot, db }= require('./models');

const vegetables = [{
      name: 'Carrot',
      color: 'Orange',
      planted_on: new Date()
    },
    {
      name: 'Cucumber',
      color: 'Green',
      planted_on: new Date()
    },
    {
      name: 'Broccoli',
      color: 'Green',
      planted_on: new Date()
    },
    {
      name: 'Eggplant',
      color: 'Purple',
      planted_on: new Date()
}];
const gardeners = [{
      name: 'Bill',
      age: 35
    },
    {
      name: 'Suzan',
      age: 45
    },
    {
      name: 'Teresa',
      age: 55
    },
    {
      name: 'Andrew',
      age: 65
}];
const plots = [{
      size: 6,
      shaded: true
    },
    {
      size: 6,
      shaded: false
    },
    {
      size: 6,
      shaded: 0
    },
    {
      size: 6,
      shaded: 1
}];

db.sync({force: true})
  .then( _ => Promise.all(vegetables.map(vegetable => Vegetable.create(vegetable))))
  .then( _ => Promise.all(gardeners.map(gard => Gardener.create(gard))))
  .then( _ => Promise.all(plots.map(pl => Plot.create(pl))))
  .then( _ => Promise.all([Vegetable.findAll(), Gardener.findAll(), Plot.findAll()]))
  .then( data => {
      let calls = [];
      for(let i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++){
          calls.push(Gardener.findById(data[0][i].dataValues.id).then(gdnr => {
              console.log(gdnr);
              //Can't figure out why this isn't a function here
              return gdnr.setOwner(data[0][i].dataValues.id);
          }));
          //Gardener.findById(data[0][i].dataValues.id).then()//set gardner to a veggie foreign
          //Plot.findById(data[0][i].dataValues.id)//set plot a gardner foreign
      }
      return Promise.all(calls);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
  .finally(() => {
    db.close();
  })
```

MODEL:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const db = new Sequelize('postgres://localhost:5432/plantr', {logging: false});

const Gardener = db.define('gardeners', {
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
  age: Sequelize.INTEGER
});

const Plot = db.define('plots', {
  size: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  shaded: Sequelize.BOOLEAN
});

const Vegetable = db.define('vegetables', {
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
  color: Sequelize.STRING,
  planted_on: Sequelize.DATE
});

Plot.belongsTo(Gardener);
Gardener.hasOne(Plot);

Vegetable.belongsToMany(Gardener, {through: 'vegetable_plot'});
Gardener.belongsToMany(Vegetable, {through: 'vegetable_plot'});

Gardener.belongsTo(Vegetable, {as: 'favorite_vegetable'});

module.exports = {
    Gardener, Plot, Vegetable, db
}
```

ERROR LOG:

```
TypeError: gdnr.setOwner is not a function
    at Gardener.findById.then.gdnr (/Users/amc/Documents/fullstack/plantr/seed.js:71:23)
    at tryCatcher (/Users/amc/Documents/fullstack/plantr/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/amc/Documents/fullstack/plantr/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/amc/Documents/fullstack/plantr/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/amc/Documents/fullstack/plantr/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/amc/Documents/fullstack/plantr/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (/Users/amc/Documents/fullstack/plantr/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (/Users/amc/Documents/fullstack/plantr/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/Users/amc/Documents/fullstack/plantr/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:763:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:734:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:716:5)
```

OBJCT LOGGED BEFORE ERROR:

```
gardeners { 
dataValues: 
   { id: 2,
     name: 'Suzan',
     age: 45,
     createdAt: 2018-05-01T02:11:53.993Z,
     updatedAt: 2018-05-01T02:11:53.993Z,
     favoriteVegetableId: null },
  _previousDataValues: 
   { id: 2,
     name: 'Suzan',
     age: 45,
     createdAt: 2018-05-01T02:11:53.993Z,
     updatedAt: 2018-05-01T02:11:53.993Z,
     favoriteVegetableId: null },
  _changed: {},
  _modelOptions: 
   { timestamps: true,
     validate: {},
     freezeTableName: false,
     underscored: false,
     underscoredAll: false,
     paranoid: false,
     rejectOnEmpty: false,
     whereCollection: { id: 2 },
     schema: null,
     schemaDelimiter: '',
     defaultScope: {},
     scopes: [],
     indexes: [],
     name: { plural: 'gardeners', singular: 'gardener' },
     omitNull: false,
     sequelize: 
      Sequelize {
        options: [Object],
        config: [Object],
        dialect: [PostgresDialect],
        queryInterface: [QueryInterface],
        models: [Object],
        modelManager: [ModelManager],
        connectionManager: [ConnectionManager],
        importCache: {},
        test: [Object] },
     hooks: {},
     uniqueKeys: {} },
  _options: 
   { isNewRecord: false,
     _schema: null,
     _schemaDelimiter: '',
     raw: true,
     attributes: 
      [ 'id',
        'name',
        'age',
        'createdAt',
        'updatedAt',
        'favoriteVegetableId' ] },
  __eagerlyLoadedAssociations: [],
  isNewRecord: false }
```

There was also an undefined logged as the function, but i figured that wouldn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get owner isn't a method available on that sequel object for the gardener because its relation to another table isn't by owner, its foreign key for the vegetable table is favorite_vegetable; so the method would be setFavorite_vegetable(vegetable id or vegetableObject).